# Forms - Equivalent to useFormContext() from React but in Blazor 8

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, server-side-rendering, react-hook-form, .net-8.0

I was working with React for at least 2 years in my past job and recently i changed to a position where the frontend is being created with Blazor 8.

I was wondering if exist any equivalent to the method useFormContext from the library react-hook-form but in Blazor.

With that hook i was able to access to values, errors and other stuff from all the inputs that were wrapped by a form tag.

I did a little research about this feature on Blazor and i found out that i can do a @bind-Form but is not able to passing it as a cascading parameter and i need to referer that @bind to all my child components wrapped with the EditForm tag.

I will be so grateful if someone shares any repo where I can find something similar to this functionality.

I research in microsoft documentation, reddit and stackoverflow and i just want to find out someone that had the same problem and try to figure out a way to avoid to pass the Form parameter component-by-component by hand.

Why i want do that?

I just want to avoid enormous form components and trying to do atomic ones.

Comment: The _Blazor way_ or rather .Net way would be to setup your view model with data annotations for validation. You don't really care about the HTML form anymore, only the state of the model that is bound to it.

Comment: Hi Chris! Im using fluent validation to validate my inputs but the main problem that i found is that i can not delegate the responsabilites for manage the inputs values into child components inside my form parent component. I need any way to bind in cascade my model and let any child to manage the values maybe i was not clear in my main post sorry about that!